# Reduce flame maximum on cooktop

Tags: equipment, stove, pot, gas

My wife always uses the maximum setting which results in flames shooting around the outside of many pots melting their plastic handles. Is there any way of reducing the maximum to keep the flames under the pots?

Comment: If the slightly obvious „turn the flame lower“ doesn’t help, does she match pot size and burner size?

Comment: Welcome to SA!  However, it seems like you're asking us to troubleshoot a marital issue, rather than a cooking problem.  This isn't the right board for that.

Comment: My cooktop has 5 burners that are different sizes. Highest on the smallest two is "OK" even for small pots, where even medium on the larger burns might be too much. If your cooktop is similar, make a rule that certain pots can only be used on certain burners.

Comment: There is an issue with some stoves, if cooking in two small pans, but with only one small burner.   The solution is still to turn the bigger burner down after lighting though; my medium burners on minimum are fine for my 16cm pans, and this has been true of all domestic gas stoves I've used.  Carefully positioning the pan may also be needed

Comment: You really shouldn't be tampering with gas appliances unless you're properly trained and certified; [it may even be illegal depending on where you are](https://www.gassaferegister.co.uk/media/1449/who-can-legally-work-on-a-gas-appliance-factsheet.pdf).

Comment: I wonder if a simmer diffuser might help here, left on unless not needed.  While it widens the heated area, heating more of the handle, it should reduce the peak temperature.  If pot skirts for  indoor gas stoves were readily available that might also help direct the heat in the right direction (or make things worse) but they seem mainly to be for camping stoves.  While I'd experiment and indeed have, I can't suggest anyone else does

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is no, there's no practical way to reduce the heat output of your cooktop without so much modification you may as well buy a new really horrible one with pathetically small burners. Then you'll hate it because it takes a calendar year to boil water for pasta.

I feel your pain with this, I've had family members break my good kitchen knives and burn the non-stick off brand new pans before I've had a chance to use them, and it is frustrating. Education and a bit of zen are what is required.

Answer (score 2):

**You need new pots and pans.**

How wonderful to have someone cook for you!  It is fun to have a powerful stovetop.  She needs better equipment to cook the way she likes to cook.  Not crappy pans with melted handles.

Go to a place that sells new pots and pans and get some all metal ones with metal handles.  There are lots of nice ones.  Buy a set.  Unwrap them and wash them and leave them out on the stove with a flower on one.

You can tell her that you wanted some things she could use that would not fall apart when she used them!  Because you like to eat what she makes.  Do not mention the melted handles.  I am sure you already did but it is not too late to not mention them again.

The handles will get hot.  She knows that already.

Tip:  even though you got new ones, don't throw out the old ones right away.  There may be some in there she likes just like I like my old carrot grater and that weird little orange glass saucepan.